# Calling children of specified index?

Tags: jquery, indexing, css-selectors, parent-child

Anyone know the proper syntax to write this statement?

```
$('.nav ul li')[0].children("a")
```

For some reason this is not working. The return is that its not a function. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this for getting the first element from the results.

```
$('.nav ul li').first().children("a")
```

Or if you need a specific index

```
$('.nav ul li').eq(0).children("a")
```

You can also use the selectors `:eq(n)` and `:first` if you want.